# Getting the selectedIndex of the currently selected tab from a viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selectedindex

I currently have an iPhone application with a tabbar and multiple viewcontrollers. All the views are designed in Interface Builder. I'd like to be able to get the currently selected index of the tabbar from the viewcontroller, but for some reason this property returns (null).

I called the following in the viewDidLoad function of my viewcontroller:

`self.tabBarController.selectedIndex`

What would be the correct way to do this?

Updated with the code of the AppDelegate class.

MyAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
  UIWindow *window;
  UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

MyAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize window, tabBarController;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
  [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [tabBarController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: What is the value of tabBarController and if not nil what class is it pointing to.

Comment: I hope I understand correctly what you mean. I'm quite the novice, which must be rather apparent from my initial question. Anyway, [self.tabBarController class] returns UITabBarController, which is to be expected, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a pointer to your tabbar in your appDelegate class. Your view has no tabbar, so you recieve nil from [self.tabBarController selectedIndex].

Comment: How can I do that? There is a pointer to tabBarController in the class. I've update the question with the code of the appDelegate class.

Comment: myAppDelegate* getAppDelegate(){
 return (myAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
you can add this method to your appdelegate class and call your tabbar by getAppDelegate().tabBarController

Comment: Is this the same as: MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex); Because this returns (null) as well, I'm afraid. And the application crashes when switching to another tab section

Comment: why the self.tabBarController.selectedIndex is nil, anyone has the answer.

Comment: when try to get the value of the tabBarController.selectedIndex, anyone can tell the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it. Using the following returns the correct index:

```
  MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"%d", appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex);
```

The reason the application was crashing was the fact that I used %@ instead of %d in the NSLog part. I could have sworn I tried %d before, strange...

The index is now returned, but only once. After you tap the tab section an index number is returned, but when you tap another section again no number is printed. Probably because the view has already been loaded once. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Use a different method? viewDidLoad is the callback that the system uses to tell your view controller that its view has just been loaded (whether from a nib file, or the code in loadView, or whatever). It may be called multiple times over the life of the controller, but only if the view was unloaded at some point in between (say, by a low-memory warning). Perhaps you're looking for something like viewWillAppear: ?

Comment: Also, this kind of clarification should really be an edit to the question, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll edit the root question in the future from now on.

Thanks for the viewDidLoad pointer, will look into that.

Comment: viewWillAppear is exactly what I was looking for! Sorry for such an obvious question, but the scope of the SDK is quite mesmerising at the moment. Thanks!